# Laravel service provider choose which class to inject

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have an API and I use sanctum API tokens as authentication.

-Let's suppose I receive a request from a user.

-Based on the user I get the user's settings from db.

-User setting "selected_class" = "foo".

How do I declare a service provider that injects the "selected_class" as implementation?

Comment: Please, check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for know how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you ServiceProvider's register method:

```
 public function register()
 {
    $this->app()->singleton()->(YOUR_CONTRACT::class, function(){
        if(request('certain_field')){
          return new CONCRETE_IMPLEMENTATION_1::class;
        }
        else{
          return new CONCRETE_IMPLEMENTATION_2::class;
        }
    });
 }
```

In  your controller you would inject your contract/interface like so, e.g through method injection:

```
public function someMethod(YOUR_CONTACT::class $concreteImplementation){
  // it will be correct implementation of your contract/interface
}
```

Comment: can I replace YOUR_COUNTRACT:class with an interface?

Comment: request("certain field") is supposed to be the user settings from db?

Comment: I  used request just for example. It' will be logic depending on which you will decide that you need which implementation of the interface, as your Service Provider will execute on each page request.

Contract is just a fancy term for Interface which Laravel uses.

Comment: ok ,but the problem is that inside the register() method I cannot access the user

Comment: You can access current user with auth()->user() anywhere. Define a relationship on user model like settings, and then access auth()->user->settings like this.

Comment: I'm sure your main Question is addressed :-)

Comment: When I try to access the user (using every way available) inside the register() method, I get an error saying "Class [hash] does not exist"

Comment: Try boot method then, register/boot usage depend on what you need. 'boot' when the entire framework is available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226273/discussion-between-develope-cruz-and-ali-raza).